# catkin_make unable to build and throws "Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2 Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed"

Tags: ros, linux, catkin-make

I have been trying to build my ROS workspace using catkin_make, where i have cloned a repo/PACKAGE. I tried many of the things mentioned in previous answers to questions similar to my issue but without any progress. I tried building another package and it worked well. I am new to ROS and Linux, and this issue has been impeding me for a 3 days now.

Many thanks in advance!

```
abouseif@abouseif-ThinkCentre-M92p:~/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 3 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - gazebo_grasp_plugin
-- ~~  - kuka_arm
-- ~~  - kr210_claw_moveit
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'gazebo_grasp_plugin'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
--   system
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   iostreams
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Found Protobuf: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so  
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Looking for OGRE...
-- OGRE_PREFIX_WATCH changed.
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'OGRE'
--   Found OGRE, version 1.9.0
-- Found Ogre Ghadamon (1.9.0)
-- Found OGRE: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Paging...
-- Found OGRE_Paging: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgrePaging.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Terrain...
-- Found OGRE_Terrain: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreTerrain.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Property...
-- Found OGRE_Property: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreProperty.so
-- Looking for OGRE_RTShaderSystem...
-- Found OGRE_RTShaderSystem: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreRTShaderSystem.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Volume...
-- Found OGRE_Volume: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreVolume.so
-- Looking for OGRE_Overlay...
-- Found OGRE_Overlay: optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreOverlay.so
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeLists.txt:32 (catkin_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kuka_arm'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- kuka_arm: 0 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kr210_claw_moveit'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kr210_claw_moveit)
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "trajectory_sampler" requests linking to directory "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/roslib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target _catkin_empty_exported_target
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target std_srvs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target std_srvs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_ros_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target gazebo_ros_gencfg
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target graph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target graph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target graph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target _kuka_arm_generate_messages_check_deps_CalculateIK
[  0%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target shape_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target graph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target graph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target shape_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target graph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _kuka_arm_generate_messages_check_deps_CalculateIK
[  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target graph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target shape_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target graph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target kuka_arm_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target shape_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Generating Python code from SRV kuka_arm/CalculateIK
Scanning dependencies of target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target kuka_arm_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 16%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 16%] Generating EusLisp code from kuka_arm/CalculateIK.srv
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_ros_planning_gencfg
[ 25%] Generating EusLisp manifest code for kuka_arm
[ 25%] Built target moveit_ros_planning_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target graph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 25%] Built target graph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target moveit_ros_manipulation_gencfg
[ 25%] Built target moveit_ros_manipulation_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target kuka_arm_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] Generating C++ code from kuka_arm/CalculateIK.srv
Scanning dependencies of target kuka_arm_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 41%] Generating Javascript code from kuka_arm/CalculateIK.srv
[ 50%] Generating Python srv __init__.py for kuka_arm
[ 50%] Built target kuka_arm_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target shape_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 50%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_grasp_fix
[ 50%] Built target kuka_arm_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target kuka_arm_generate_messages_lisp
[ 58%] Generating Lisp code from kuka_arm/CalculateIK.srv
[ 58%] Built target kuka_arm_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target kuka_arm_generate_messages_lisp
[ 75%] Building CXX object RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/src/GazeboGraspFix.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/src/GazeboGraspGripper.cpp.o
[ 75%] Built target kuka_arm_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target kuka_arm_generate_messages
Scanning dependencies of target trajectory_sampler
[ 75%] Built target kuka_arm_generate_messages
[ 83%] Building CXX object RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp.o
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp: In constructor ‘TrajectorySampler::TrajectorySampler(ros::NodeHandle)’:
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:180:43: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
     bool success = move_group.plan(my_plan);
                                           ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:224:15: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in assignment
       success = move_group.execute(my_plan);
               ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:291:39: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
         bool worked = move_group.move();
                                       ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:313:13: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in assignment
     success = move_group.move();
             ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:339:13: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in assignment
     success = move_group.move();
             ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:351:13: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in assignment
     success = move_group.plan(my_plan);
             ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:375:15: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in assignment
       success = move_group.execute(my_plan);
               ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:452:39: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
         bool worked = move_group.move();
                                       ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:497:13: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in assignment
     success = move_group.move();
             ^
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp: In member function ‘bool TrajectorySampler::OperateGripper(const bool&)’:
/home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp:543:33: error: cannot convert ‘moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
   bool success = eef_group.move();
                                 ^
RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3178: recipe for target 'RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 91%] Linking CXX shared library /home/abouseif/main/udacity/roboticsnd/robotics_term1/ROS/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_grasp_fix.so
[ 91%] Built target gazebo_grasp_fix
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Comment: I think you can try installing missing dependencies first by running `rosdep update` and then `rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src -y` from your `catkin_ws/src` directory.

Comment: Does it works? I got exactly the same problem

Comment: @PetchPuttichai Thanks for the answer. And yes i did, but without any success. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Carlos No Carlos, not for me at least, you should try it yourself, maybe it will work for you. I am using the VM image provided by Udacity instead now. If i find a solution for this problem, i will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Met similar problem.

Changed 
    `bool success = move_group.move()`
to
    `bool success = move_group.move() == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS`

<s>Perhaps the update is messing with the code.</s> https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/14949/19080

Answer (score 1):

This is because of using a newer version of gcc compiler (C++11).

Use `static_cast<bool>()` to resolve the issue.

example: change

```
success = move_group.move();
```

to

```
success = static_cast<bool>(move_group.move());
```

Comment: Muthama's answer worked well for me, thanks. Use static_cast<bool>() to resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @Sebas. On StackExchange *answers* need to answer the question. StackExchange isn't a discussion forum, it's a place to ask questions and get answers. If you wish to discuss a question or answer you can use [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). If you have an idea for how a question or answer can be improved, you can comment when you have [comment privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Please review [ask] and [about] for more information on how StackExchange works.

Comment: Also, the best way to indicate that an answer is useful is to click on the "This answer is useful" button (the up arrow) next to the answer. That way good answers rise to the top and the people who write them get a reward in the form of increased reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason:
make operator bool() explicit in MoveItErrorCode
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/commit/4033e577b64ab7ef0e4473342168494f69ef9324

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* isobe. Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked to content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Running `catkin_make -j8` in my catkin workspace in the Python base environment, the error message was `Invoking "make -j8" failed` instead of `Invoking "make -j4 -l4“ failed"`.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 43, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named em
util/ros_canopen/can_msgs/CMakeFiles/can_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target '/home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/include/can_msgs/Frame.h' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/include/can_msgs/Frame.h] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1641: recipe for target 'util/ros_canopen/can_msgs/CMakeFiles/can_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [util/ros_canopen/can_msgs/CMakeFiles/can_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  4%] Built target can_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  4%] Linking CXX executable /home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/lib/robot_localization/test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher
[  4%] Built target test_ros_robot_localization_listener_publisher
[  4%] Linking CXX shared library /home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/lib/libddynamic_reconfigure.so
[  4%] Built target ddynamic_reconfigure
[  6%] Linking CXX shared library /home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/lib/libros_filter_utilities.so
[  6%] Built target ros_filter_utilities
[  6%] Linking CXX executable /home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/lib/socketcan_interface/socketcan_dump
[  6%] Built target socketcan_dump
[  6%] Linking CXX shared library /home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/lib/libcomplementary_filter.so
[  6%] Built target complementary_filter
[  7%] Linking CXX shared library /home/stu16291/rosyard/devel/lib/libvelodyne_sensor_plugin.so
[  7%] Built target velodyne_sensor_plugin
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8" failed
```

Solution was to remove the catkin workspace and install it again.

Remove:
In your catkin workspace, usually your project folder, delete (or rename with suffix "_old" if you want to compare the not working catkin workspace later with the working catkin workspace):

- build
- devel
- optionally src/CMakeLists.txt (I did that, not sure if it is really needed)

Source:
[Removing catkin workspace](https://answers.ros.org/question/66012/removing-catkin-workspace/?answer=66014#post-id-66014)

Afterwards, the fresh `catkin_make -j8` in my catkin workspace in the Python base environment installed without errors.